# probability by permutation

Tags: probability

I tried to solve this question. My solution is below.

Please could you tell me if it is correct or not?

If 3 books are picked at random from a shelf containing
5 novels, 3 books of poems, and a dictionary,
what is the probability that:

(a) the dictionary is selected?
(b) 2 novels and 1 book of poems are selected?

Answers:

(a) $$\frac{\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}} +\frac{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{9}{3}} $$

(b) $$\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{9}{3}} + \frac{\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}}$$

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add the self-study tag.

Comment: Yes, I think it is correct

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your reasoning.

Comment: Perhaps @YilunZhang should also explain why he/she thinks the answers are correct.

Comment: Why are you adding rather than multiplying in both (a) and (b)?

Comment: Manal, this looks like a routine [textbook-style question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Please read that link and address Andy's question.

Comment: With the dictionary question, note that it doesn't matter what the remaining books are. You can consider the shelf to consist of 1 dictionary and 8 non-dictionaries. That simplifies the question.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in the problem are small enough that you can solve this problem by simply listing all possible cases and counting.  Here is something to start you off
for part (b). Call the 5 novels N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, and make a list of all possible
pairs of novels starting with

N1, N2,

N1, N3,

.....

and ending with

N4, N5.

If your list has more than (or less than!)  $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ pairs,
go back and correct it.  Now add in P1 or P2 or P3 into each of the
10 pairs of novels.....

Answer (score 0):

I like to simulate the process of sampling from the shelf and then check for the conditions stated under (a) and (b). If you run this R code you'll find that the probability of a sample containing a dictionary is approximately $1/3$ (`p_a` below) and that the probability of a sample containing 2 novels and 1 poem is approximately $5/14$ (`p_b` below).

```
# define your shelf
# - 5 novels
# - 3 poems
# - 1 dictionary
shelf <- rep(x = c("novel", "poem", "dict"), times = c(5, 3, 1))

# a
# pull n_a samples of size three from the shelf
# the proportion of samples with a dictionary approximates the answer to (a)
n_a <- 1000
p_a <- sum(replicate(n = n_a, expr = {
    s <- sample(x = shelf, size = 3, replace = FALSE)
    ifelse(test = is.element(el = "dict", set = s), yes = 1, no = 0)}))/n_a

# b
# pull n_b samples of size three from the shelf
# the proportion of samples with two novels and a poen approximates the answer to (b)
n_b <- 1000
p_b <- sum(replicate(n = n_b, expr = {
    s <- sort(x = sample(x = shelf, size = 3, replace = FALSE))
    res <- sort(x = c("novel", "novel", "poem"))
    ifelse(test = identical(x = res, y = s), yes = 1, no = 0)}))/n_b
```

Comment: +1 for the answer and the R code. looks like i made a mistake!